# Show 'Closest' div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Wonder if someone could point in the right direction here i'm trying to show the 'next' element on page with the matching class name i.e. the one directly underneath the link.

```js
$(function() {
  $("div.std-centered").hide();
  $("a.show_hide").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('div.std-centered').next().show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col sameHeight">
    <p>Some blurb <a href="#" class="show_hide">i</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col text-center sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center col sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center col sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center col sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 std-centered">
    <p>This is the content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The div with the class `std-centered` is hidden (in jQuery) and I'm trying to find and show it when the `show_hide` link is clicked.

But I just can't seem to get a handle on that div. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,
C

Comment: $(this).closest gets the closest parent matching the selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because `closest()` searches up the DOM to find parent elements, yet the `.std-centered` div is a sibling of a parent and hence will not be found.

To fix this you could instead use `closest()` to find the `.row`, then the `next('.row')` and finally `find()` to get the element you want, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("div.std-centered").hide();
  
  $("a.show_hide").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.row').next('.row').find('div.std-centered').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col sameHeight">
    <p>Some blurb <a href="#" class="show_hide">i</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col text-center sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center col sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center col sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center col sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 std-centered">
    <p>This is the content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HI, thanks for that......this is really odd. It works in your code snippet but doesn't work on my page! Getting no developer console errors just nothing's happening!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this selector `$(this).closest('div.row').next(".row").find('.std-centered').show();`
2. `Closest()` -> find the first parent with specified parameter

```js
$(function() {
  $("div.std-centered").hide();
  $("a.show_hide").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('div.row').next(".row").find('.std-centered').show();// since element std-centered is found in row tthat is next to row that is closest to show_hide
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col sameHeight">
    <p>Some blurb <a href="#" class="show_hide">click</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col text-center sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center col sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center col sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center col sameHeight">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 std-centered">
    <p>This is the content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```